# xpath get node from inside value

Tags: xpath, simplexml

Current xpath: `Product/ProductMultimediaObject/MultimediaObject`

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [ContentType] => application/pdf
                    [Date] => 2014-11-01 01:20:35
                    [Description] => Leaflet
                )

        )

)
```

But I'm currently just hoping that the found `MultimediaObject` is the correct one - which is not. I need to get the `MultimediaObject` where `Description` has a specific value.

What I've tried:

```
Product/ProductMultimediaObject/MultimediaObject[Description/text() = 'WhatIWant']
Product/ProductMultimediaObject/MultimediaObject/Description[text() = 'WhatIWant']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Desciption is an attribute. Try

```
Product/ProductMultimediaObject/MultimediaObject[@Description = 'WhatIWant']
```

or, for short,

```
//MultimediaObject[@Description = 'WhatIWant']
```